# Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'currencySeperator' could not be found

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting an error when I try to use my custom pipe in a template:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'currencySeperator' could not be found
```

Here is `CurrencySeperatorPipe`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'currencySeperator'
    })
    export class  CurrencySeperatorPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(value: any, decimalSp: string = ',', thousandSp: string = '.'): number {
            return this.localeString(value,decimalSp,thousandSp);
        }

        missingOneDecimalCheck(nStr) {
            nStr += '';
            const x = nStr.split(',')[1];
            if (x && x.length === 1) return true;
            return false;
        }

        missingAllDecimalsCheck(nStr) {
            nStr += '';
            const x = nStr.split(',')[1];
            if (!x) return true;
            return false;
        }

        localeString(nStr,decimalSp,thousandSp) {
            if (nStr === '') return '';
            let x, x1, x2, rgx, y1, y2;
            nStr += '';
            x = nStr.split(thousandSp);
            x1 = x[0];
            x2 = x.length > 1 ? decimalSp + x[1] : '';
            rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
            while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + thousandSp + '$2');
            }

            /** If value was inputed by user, it could have many decimals(up to 7)
                so we need to reformat previous x1 results */
            if (x1.indexOf(decimalSp) !== -1) {
                y1 = x1.slice(x1.lastIndexOf(decimalSp)).replace(/\./g, '');

                y2 = x1.split(decimalSp);
                x = y2[0] + y1;
            } else {
                x = x1 + x2;
                if (this.missingOneDecimalCheck(x)) return x += '0';
                if (this.missingAllDecimalsCheck(x)) return x += `${decimalSp}00`;
            }

            return x;
        }
    }
```

So I created **pipe.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CurrencySeperatorPipe } from './currency-seperator.pipe';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [CurrencySeperatorPipe],
      imports: [],
      exports:[CurrencySeperatorPipe]
    })
    export class PipeModule {
      static forRoot() {
        return {
          ngModule: PipeModule,
          providers: [],
        };
      }
    }
```

I imported this module to **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
...
    PipeModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    ModalComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I try to use **{{price | currencySeperator:',':'.'}}** like this in a template  it gives me this error.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not certain, but in the forRoot, don't you need to add the pipe in the providers array? To declare that this module provides this pipe? Could you also share the code for your pipe?

Comment: are you sure you've spelled 'currencySeperator' correctly in your `Pipe` declaration. And in what component are you using this pipe? It should be declared in the AppModule, or as a lazy loaded module

Comment: @Milton added CurrencySeperatorPipe

Comment: @kodcu can you show the component where you use it? And where this component is declared

Comment: @PoulKruijt  I am using in template.html files. Component declared in the PipeModule

Comment: @kodcu don't forget to import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common" in your pipe.module.ts.

Comment: @pbachman I added but it doesnt work still

Comment: @kodcu I see no component in the `PipeModule`. In what template are you using your pipe, and where is that component belonging to the template declared? In which module

Comment: @PoulKruijt updated the question. Declared at PipieModule

Comment: @kodcu I'm talking about the component where you use the pipe, not the module where you declare the pipe

Comment: @kodcu you need to import the PipeModule in the module where the component which uses the pipe too.

Comment: I did this. But it doesnt work also

Comment: @pbachman  sorry I declared this in wrong module. I fixed the error. Many thanks. Bu I couldnt understand when we declared at app.module.ts why it doesnt work?

Comment: @kodcu read my first comment, you need to import a module which declares and exports said pipe, or declare it in the module you use it

Comment: @PoulKruijt you are right. I couldnt understand very well. Could you explan why it doesnt work app.module.ts . Because it is root module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to import the PipeModule in the AppModule, but in the module where the component that uses the pipe belongs.